# Find $\lim_{z\to 0}|\sin(1/z)/\sin(z)|, z\in \mathbb{C}?$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find $$\lim_{z\to 0} \ \left|\frac{\sin(1/z)}{\sin(z)} \right|, z\in \mathbb{C}$$

I'm pretty sure that this limit doesn't exist, but i am not able to prove it.

Comment: A slightly trickier version of this, incidentally, is $\lim_{z\to 0}\left|\sin(1/z)\sin(z)\right|$ - that one _does_ converge along the real line.  After you understand this problem I encourage you to try that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the sequence
$$
z_n=\frac2{(2n+1)\pi}
$$
and the sequence
$$
z_n=\frac1{n\pi}
$$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the limit doesn't even exist as you approach zero along the real line, and that should be easy to prove — exhibit a sequence $z_n\to 0$ with the numerator of your expression bounded away from zero, and then use the standard bound on $\sin(z_n)$ as $z_n\to 0$ to show that the function goes to infinity on this sequence.  Likewise, you should be able to exhibit a sequence $w_n\to 0$ with the numerator of your expression (and thus the expression itself) identically $0$ on $w_n$.

Answer (score 0):

You should first see if that limit exists for *real* $x$. If it doesn't, then it can't exist for complex $x$.